# After receiving notification on the lock screen and entering Passcode, the user is not taken to the app

Tags: ios, notifications, passwords, alert, lockscreen

My app is successfully notifying the user when an activity is due by displaying an alert/banner on the iOS device lock screen. So up to here, no issue.

When the user swipes the alert/banner they are taken directly to the app. Again no issue here.

Here's where it becomes problematic:

If the user has set up Passcode, iOS is forcing them to enter their password after they swipe the alert/banner (which is normal). But once they enter their passcode, it is not taking them directly to the application. Instead they're on the home screen and they have to click on the application to get in and to see the notification.

So my question is how is it possible to have the user taken directly to app after they have entered their password?

I thought this passcode issue was a default behaviour from iOS until I found out that Pinterest app can take you straight to the app after you've entered your password. And their stuff works pretty clean.

Any solution/advice/method here would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Armand, how did you solve this problem?  Please add an answer if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What is your app doing when the notification is swiped? Is it trying to access Core Data?

My suggestion is to see if there is anything your app is doing when the local notification is swiped that could cause it to crash due to the lock screen being on. This would have the effect of never taking the user into your app.

(I had a passcode issue with my app. When a location event is received, it creates a local notification. In the process it needs to access Core Data. When the lock screen is on, the app could not access Core Data. It crashed silently when trying to do so. I never saw my local notification in the lock screen. Very hard to debug!)